# "TypeError: Cannot set property 'VibrantImg' in RactiveJS adaptor

Tags: ractivejs

I'm trying to create a simple Ractive adaptor to parse a value from the Color Thief (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) into a template with a defined mustache. (I know there may be better ways to achieve this, but there is a reason for why I'm using the adaptor route!)

I've set up a demo of what I have so far [here](https://codepen.io/alexlibby/pen/mwdLdo) - this the Ractive code part:

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
var img2 = document.getElementById('ctimage');
var imgColor;

Ractive.adapt.CTImg = {
  filter: function ( object ) {
    return object instanceof img2;
  },
  wrap: function ( ractive, img2, keypath, prefixer ) {
   // Setup

   return {
     teardown: function(){
       colorThief.destroy();
     },
     get: function(){
       imgColor = colorThief.getColor(img); 
     },
     set: function(property, value){
       ractive.set('mainColor', imgColor);
     },
     reset: function(value){
     }
   }
  }
};  


var ractive = new Ractive({
  target: '#container',
  template: '#template',
  adapt: [ 'CTImg' ],
  data: {
    mainColor: "rgb(97, 79, 112)"   // this is what should be returned
  }
});
```

My aim is to get the prominent color from the image given in the Codepen (above), pass it into Ractive (and to Color Thief by the adaptor), then output the resulting color on screen in the relevant mustache.

I can display a hard coded color OK in the template, so I know that the data keypath / reference is OK. However, my issue is getting the color back from Color Thief via the adaptor - the error I'm getting is Uncaught "TypeError: Cannot set property 'CTImg' of undefined".

I've checked through SO and the Ractive Github site to see if I can figure out what is going wrong, but my head is starting to spin!

Can anyone please help me to at least get the color to come back from Color Thief via the adaptor?

Comment: We can't really say for sure if it's Ractive, ColorThief or your code. `VibrantImg` isn't even present in the provided code. If you can provide a full example, that would be great.

Comment: Oops - sorry: my fault! The code is good, but the reference "VibrantImg" was to using a different library to achieve the same result, but without success. I've amended the error returned to what it should be - please let me know if you need me to post the full HTML markup/mustache code.

Answer (score 0):

So `adapt` and `adaptors` are two different config objects. `adaptors` is a registry of adaptor definitions and `adapt` tells the component/instance what adaptors to use. There's no global `adapt` property.

For global registration of an adaptor, you need `Ractive.adaptors`.

```
Ractive.adaptors.CTImg = {...}
```

The next problem is actually how you use the adaptor. Adaptors require you to put the non-POJO data into the instance. The `filter` is run on the data and determines if the data needs to be adapted, and if so, does the setup. Then, it's the usual adaptor setup. `get` returns the value to Ractive, `set` sets the value to your custom object, etc.

Here's an updated example:

```
Ractive.adaptors.CTImg = {
  filter: function ( object ) {
    // Detect if the data is an image element
    return object instanceof HTMLImageElement;
  },
  wrap: function ( ractive, object, keypath, prefixer ) {
    // Set up color thief for this piece of data because it's an image
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();

    return {
      teardown: function(){
        colorThief.destroy();
      },
      get: function(){
        // Return the replacement data
        return colorThief.getColor(object);
      },
      set: function(property, value){
        // We're not setting to color thief, leave empty
      },
      reset: function(value){
        // Always replace the data when the data is changed
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
};

var ractive = new Ractive({
  target: '#container',
  template: '#template',
  adapt: [ 'CTImg' ],
  data: {
    dominant: null
  },
  onrender: function(){
    // set image on data. adaptor will capture it.
    this.set('dominant', this.find('#ctimage'))
  }
});
```

Comment: Good spot - thankyou! I've updated my demo - it's not erroring, but is still not displaying the color value to appear in my (updated) demo. This core code:

var colorThief = new ColorThief();
var img = document.getElementById('vibimage');
imgColor = colorThief.getColor(img);
ractive.set('dominant', imgColor.toString());

...produces what I need, setting "98,79,112" in the empty div underneath "Dominant color:" in the demo. I suspect I need to set the above code in the "get" method of my adaptor - can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @AlexLibby Updated answer.

Comment: I've just tried it - thanks a million for your help: it's perfect!